# Can Webpack build PostCSS without a JavaScript file?

Tags: webpack, postcss

I have some a general, reusable stylesheet to build that is not associated with a single JavaScript file. Is it possible for Webpack to process a PostCSS file directly? Such as:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.pcss$/, loader: "postcss" },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: "/css/",
        filename: '[name].css'
    },
    entry: {
        bootstrap: 'pcss/base/styles.pcss'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement simple workaround by using [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader):

```
entry: {
    bootstrap: 'file?name=[name].[ext]!pcss/base/styles.pcss'
}
```

In this case your file will be saved separately from the entry point.

Comment: Thank you! That did it, though I still need to use the ExtractTextPlugin. This does negate the need for the index.js file. I wrote a webpack plugin to delete that index.js asset, which I am now using to delete the styles.pcss file.